# remove user from local administrators group via cmd line when username has space

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I am trying to execute a seemingly simple command, however I am having issues because the username has a space in it.

The user is: ad\local workstation admins (under the local administrators group)

The command is: net localgroup administrators ad\local workstation admins /delete

Which returns:
There is no such global user or group: ad\local.
There is no such global user or group: workstation.
There is no such global user or group: admins.

I have tried a different number of variations using quotes and brackets to no avail.

Comment: It seems to me this is more of a ServerFault question than a StackOverflow question.

Comment: The answer given by Mureinik (now deleted) and again by Scott C works perfectly for me.  What version of Windows are you running?  Are you testing using a standard `cmd.exe` console window?

Answer (score 2):

Just protect the user in quotes

```
net localgroup administrators "ad\local workstation admins" /delete
```